# A good measure for skewed values

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, skewness, weighted-mean

I have a table with the list of values as shown below. A Model Number is like a parent Disease. The below table can be read as Patients under Model Number 200(Stroke) are 2.456 more likely to have Liver failure. So there are multiple model Numbers that have liver failure and their corresponding likelihood scores are listed below. What is a good measure to look at the likelihood score across multiple model numbers for a sub category - Liver Failure.

```
+--------------+----------------------+-------+
| Model Number | Sub category         | Beta  |
+--------------+----------------------+-------+
| 200          | Liver Failure        | 2.456 |
+--------------+----------------------+-------+
| 293          | Liver Failure        | 3.567 |
+--------------+----------------------+-------+
| 343          | Liver Failure        | 1.356 |
+--------------+----------------------+-------+
| 547          | Liver Failure        | 0.642 |
+--------------+----------------------+-------+
| 322          | Liver Failure        | 0.223 |
+--------------+----------------------+-------+
| 11           | Liver Failure        | 0.442 |
+--------------+----------------------+-------+
| 28           | Liver Failure        | 0.236 |
+--------------+----------------------+-------+
| 111          | Liver Failure        | 0.235 |
+--------------+----------------------+-------+
| 603          | Liver Failure        | 0.134 |
+--------------+----------------------+-------+
```

I did the descriptive statistics for the above table, but I'm not able to decide on a good measure to read the value across multiple model numbers. The data can be skewed. I tried Average but that doesn't make sense if the data is skewed. What is a better way to compare the data across multiple model numbers as a whole (a single measure - average, standard deviation etc?)

```
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Beta                    |             |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Mean                    | 1.032333333 |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Standard Error          | 0.404641233 |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Median                  | 0.442       |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Mode                    | #N/A        |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Standard Deviation      | 1.2139237   |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Sample Variance         | 1.47361075  |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Kurtosis                | 1.278416243 |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Skewness                | 1.497787196 |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Range                   | 3.433       |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Minimum                 | 0.134       |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Maximum                 | 3.567       |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Sum                     | 9.291       |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Count                   | 9           |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Confidence Level(95.0%) | 0.933104358 |
+-------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: The median, which is the middle data point, is good for skewed data. If these are odds ratios, it's invalid to add them up anyway, which rules out mean and standard deviation.

Comment: Could you explain what your comparison is intended to accomplish? What would be the meaning or relevance of any descriptive measure of skewness (or, indeed, any other statistic) for these values?

Comment: If they are odds ratios, it might make sense to work on the average of the logs, which should be equal to the geometric mean of the odds ratios.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to first see if the data is skewed or not. The Pearson Index is a good place to start to check for data skewing. The equation is: 
$$
\begin{equation}
PI=\frac{3(\bar{X}-median)}{s}
\end{equation}$$
In this equation, PI is the Pearson Index. $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean, median is the median, and s is the sample standard deviation. So for your data the equation would look something like the following:
$$
\begin{equation}
PI=\frac{3(1.032-0.442)}{1.214}
\end{equation}$$

If the result of this is greater than or equal to +1 OR less than or equal to -1, the data is significantly skewed. The skew calculated here, which it seems was also calculated for you, is around 1.46.

It depends on if you want exact values or more generalized assumptions. If you want exact values, you could try to normalize your data. A common way of doing this is taking the natural log of the data or applying a power until the data fits a more normal curve. This could look something like: $log(x)$ or $new data=data^{0.5}$. There are articles saying that you should instead try glm/glmz and then correct that data based on it. I will link the article here: [Don't Log Transform](https://www.r-bloggers.com/do-not-log-transform-count-data-bitches/)

If you have any other questions, let me know. I don't know a lot about statistics, but I know enough to be dangerous, and hopefully giving this some attention should bring some more advanced people in too :D